# Mobile Apps. IPad. Hepler in the fields

Tags: mobile, xpages

I have a very easy application, allowing the users to enter the Data on iPad. However, when the user starts typing the text into the text field (using the xp:inputText), he gets the helper text, which is then automatically taken, if one either presses "space" or "forward" (in german it's called "weiter", hopefully it's the correct translation). So, it happens often, when the user types fast that at the end the wrong data is entered.

I don't know how to avoid it using the iOs own tools. I would be thankful if anybody tells me.

And, basically, is there any way to at least switch off or at the best to control these helpers *from* XPages side ?

No TypeAhead is used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable These features by adding two html attributes to your xp:inputText:

- autocapitalize="off"
- autocorrect="off"

You should check the the autocomplete option too.

Hope this helps

Sven

Comment: You won't be able to add them as they are not part of xp:inputText.

Comment: What about the attribute list?

Comment: Actually yes! yours is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

This example should work. Modified to use the two methods. Field 1 = (svens), Field 2 = change at runtime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:inputText id="inputText1">
        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr name="autocorrect" value="off" rendered="true"></xp:attr>
            <xp:attr name="autocapitalize" value="off" rendered="true"></xp:attr>
        </xp:this.attrs></xp:inputText>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText2"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="true"
        refreshMode="norefresh">
        <xp:this.script>
<![CDATA[document.getElementById("#{id:inputText2}").setAttribute("autocorrect", "off");
document.getElementById("#{id:inputText2}").setAttribute("autocapitalize", "off");
]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this will make the second field disable the autocorrect/capitalize for the iPad.

Comment: Svens option is probably better. There will be an "Attrs" option in the "All Properties" of the control. You can add the related attributes there.

Comment: Simon, by the way, if i need to process many fields, your solution would make the source code shorter

Comment: after the testing i noticed that simply using document.getElementById("{id:inputText2}") doesn't seem to work. When i look into the source code, the fields which are defined with this method don't have the attributes. The fields defined with the first method (from Sven) are Ok... Any ideas ?

Comment: You won't see the attributes in the source, but if you check within the live console of the browser you will see they have them.

I need to fix my server at home to test it on my iPad though. :/

Comment: Just tested on my iPad and both options work. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: hmm, could it be that i don't get the needed result because of the fact that i'm using both "xe:appPage" and "xe:singlePageApp" and, therefore if i need to the Element by ID i have to specify something else not the simply document.getElementById("{id:inputText2}") ? How do you think ?